# Word automate footer text

Tags: ms-office

After many years in the TeX universe I'm forced to use MS Word 2010 for work.

In my document I've got a version number and the corresponding date on the cover page and in the footer. Footers on odd and even pages have a different layout so that page numbers are always on the outer side of page and the front-section is numbered with roman numbers.

This means I need to change the version number and date in 5 places. There has to be a way to create linked fields so that the data can be updated in a singele place.

Comment: You can use field codes to create variables.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Docpropertys did the trick. Here's a good tutorial: kalliopeia.edu.gr/Fix-IT/?p=121